# How to spec a MOV resistor

Tags: surge-protection, mov

I want to add a resistor before my MOV. The largest surge I will have will be 3kV.

I came across this [datasheet](https://www.bourns.com/docs/Product-Datasheets/MOV07D.pdf).

If the most voltage my load can handle is 1kV surge, what will the resistor value be?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fj7YmK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What's your load current, which specific MOV, and what's the input voltage range?

Comment: @JohnD around 1.3A

Comment: There were three questions, could you answer the other two please? (Note: "input voltage range" includes what kind of surge you're protecting against.)

Comment: @JoeyB If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few pointers: -

- The surge generator will have a defined output resistance that is stated in the specification of the surge you are trying to meet.
- This output resistance may be enough to avoid adding your own current limiting resistor.
- So, decide on which surge type you are wanting to protect against and choose a surge specification based on (say) EN 61000
- For instance, EN 61000-4-5 surge testing defines the task of the described laboratory test as to find the reaction of the EUT under specified operational conditions, to surge voltages caused by switching and lightning effects at certain threat levels. (words taken from [here](https://keystonecompliance.com/iec-61000-4-5/#:%7E:text=EN%2061000%2D4%2D5%20surge,effects%20at%20certain%20threat%20levels.))
- But you may be only contemplating ESD protection and you can choose a different EN 61000 sub-spec such as [EN 61000-4-2](https://absolute-emc.com/standard/International_Test_Standards/iecen-61000-4-2#:%7E:text=IEC%2061000%2D4%2D2%20is,human%20body%20or%20metal%20objects.)

The point I'm labouring here is that you need to decide what surge you are trying to withstand and capitalize on the inherent limiting resistor defined in that specification.

Then I'd use a simulator to model the circuit and see how much energy stress was inflicted on the MOV and, whether you need to add more resistance (as per your R1). You might be surprised how simple these things are to model and simulate.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at more than volts when specifying MOVs. They are variable devices, so will respond differently to a 3kV pulse from static electricity (low capacitance, maybe 1 milli-Joule of energy), versus a 3kV pulse from a 1000µF capacitor bank (4500 Joules = extremely dangerous - this device would vaporize.)

Looking at the [Bourns MOV-07DxxxK Series](https://www.bourns.com/docs/Product-Datasheets/MOV07D.pdf) datasheet, the "largest" device of that series is the MOV-07D821K.  That device:

- Max *continuous* voltage allowed across it: 510VAC or 675VDC.
- Voltage at which 1mA will flow through it: 738VDC minimum, 820VDC nominal, 902VDC max.
- For max 20µs, the device may conduct 10A current (40 Joules max), at which it will have at most 1355VDC across it.
- It can conduct 1200A for <=8µs (40J max.)  Note in this condition it will have *even more* voltage across it.
- Has 72pF parasitic capacitance.